# QT, qApp->applicationDirPath and CMakeLists

Tags: qt, cmake

I have an application that compiles and runs perfectly fine with QT-Creator (setup#1).

I just created a CMakeLists file, so that people can compile this without using QT-Creator (setup#2), just with cmake.

The compilation with setup#2 is successful. However, when I run the application, some paths get a weird value.

For example, I have the code snippet:

```
        QDir                   qdir( qApp->applicationDirPath() );
                               qdir.cdUp();
                               qdir.cdUp();
        QString         PATH = qdir.path() + "/config/" + QString( ui->myPaths_TextBox_Filename_INPUT_TXT->toPlainText() );
```

When I run this with setup#1, the `PATH` string has a valid path.
When I run this with setup#2, the `PATH` string has a weird path, like:

```
"/home/dimitris/.local/share/Trash/config/INPUT_PATHS.txt"
```

pointing to something in the trash folder.

What is the reason for this and what is a possible solution? Up to now I cannot find a valid reason for this online.

UPDATE:

The content of the CMakeLists file:

```
project(RGBD_HAND_TRACKER)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# makes sure that it is compiled with 02 (O3 and up gives bad result)
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2"
    CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for All Builds" FORCE)
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g"
    CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for Debug Builds" FORCE)
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  "-DNDEBUG"
    CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO  "-DNDEBUG"
    CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL  "-DNDEBUG"
    CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)

find_package( PkgConfig )
pkg_check_modules( EIGEN3 REQUIRED eigen3 )
include_directories( ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Opencv required
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${OPENCV_DEFINITIONS})

message("\n Found OpenCV \n")

# OpenGL required
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

find_package (Threads)

# QT4 required
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL REQUIRED)
set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

message("\n Found QT4 \n")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR} )

# PCL required
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common features filters io kdtree octree surface search) # keypoints registration sample_consensus segmentation tracking visualization apps io_ply
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

message("\n Found PCL \n")

# BOOST required
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

message("\n Found BOOST \n")

# BULLET required
find_package( Bullet REQUIRED COMPONENTS BulletDynamics BulletCollision BulletLinearMath 2.82 ) # BulletLinearMath BulletSoftBody
include_directories( ${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

message("\n Found BULLET \n")

# GLM required
#INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PATH_GLM} )
include_directories( ../libraries/glm )

message("\n Found GLM \n")

# LIBCONFIG required
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package( LibConfig REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${LIBCONFIGPP_INCLUDE_DIR} )
#set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LIBCONFIG_LIBRARIES})

message("\n Found LIBCONFIG \n")

# GLPK required
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package( GLPK REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${GLPK_INCLUDE_DIR} )

message("\n Found GLPK \n")

# MPFR required
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package( MPFR REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${MPFR_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_definitions(${MPFR_DEFINITIONS})

message("\n Found MPFR \n")

# GMP required
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package( GMP REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${GMP_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_definitions(${GMP_DEFINITIONS})

message("\n Found GMP \n")

# CGAL required
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package( CGAL REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_definitions(${CGAL_DEFINITIONS})

message("\n Found CGAL \n")

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

file(GLOB VIEWER_SOURCES src/*.cpp)

file(GLOB VIEWER_INCLUDES include/*.h)

#set QT forms
SET(QT_FORMS
    ui/mainwindow.ui
)

# create moc for QT
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC ${QT_HEADERS})

# process ui
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HEADERS ${QT_FORMS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(RGBD_HAND_TRACKER ${VIEWER_SOURCES} ${VIEWER_INCLUDES}
${QT_HEADERS}
${QT_MOC}
${QT_FORMS})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(RGBD_HAND_TRACKER ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}     ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}     ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_FEATURES_LIBRARIES} 
${PCL_FILTERS_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_KDTREE_LIBRARIES}     ${PCL_OCTREE_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_SURFACE_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_SEARCH_LIBRARIES} 
${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARIES} 
${BULLET_DYNAMICS_LIBRARY} ${BULLET_COLLISION_LIBRARY} LinearMath 
${LIBCONFIGPP_LIBRARIES} ${GLPK_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_LIBRARIES}         ${MPFR_LIBRARIES} 
) # ${BULLET_LINEARMATH_LIBRARY} ${BULLET_SOFTBODY_LIBRARY}
set_property(TARGET RGBD_HAND_TRACKER PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS QT_SHARED _REENTRANT)
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered. Not enough data.

Comment: Please give me some hints as to what would be helpful additional info, I'll be more than happy to provide this.

Comment: If the code is correct, and that your qmake works is a good hint it is, the problem lies in your CMakeLists.txt. So the CMakeLists.txt is of interest. Even then it will be hard to debug, since everything depends on parameters, which are unique to your system. My guess? The executables, which are created by your qmake and your cmake project lie in different folders. This is the only sensible explanation that you have different applicationDirPath() values.

Comment: What you say makes sense. Yes, the code is perfectly fine, the problem is the CMakeLists file for sure. Could it be `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` to blame? It was a solution for another problem, but maybe this has implications.

Comment: No, that's definitely no the problem. This just lets cmake scan your project folder and run moc on files, which need it.

Comment: Below the line `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)` add `message(${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH})`. Then run cmake. This will output where cmake puts the executables... not that you don't know this anyways when you start the program. Are your setup#1 and setup#2 executables really in the same folder? Looks to me you create setup#1... you execute it and it shows correct path. Then you delete setup#1 and create setup#2. But then for some reason you don't execute setup#2, but setup#1, which lies at this point in the trash bin. Do you have a shortcut created?

Comment: What you say is might be true, because now I see that even when I add some couts in the code at the line where I print the PATH string, I don't get this extra output. Probably I still run the deleted executable of setup#1 as you say. I'll try now what you propose.

Comment: As you say, when I delete setup#1 and create#2, I run compile in one terminal tab, and I run the executable in another terminal tab (ubuntu 12.04). After deleting setup#1, although this is not visible in the terminal, the executable that is run is the one that now lies in the trash folder. By CD-ing in the proper directory where the new executable lies, the output is now as expected. So it is not a source-code or CMakeLists problem, but Ubuntu's terminal was the issue, by running an executable at a different location than the one displayed.. Thank you very much for your help and your time!